# Hub sticking - friction

Tags: hub, rims, freehub

Bike I got used and happy with the price for frame alone but I don't know the history.

Kris King hub with significant drag. 
With cassette off and just a rim if spin it hard I get 5 revolutions. 
I have a backup wheel and if I spin it hard I get 50 revolutions. 
I can feel a lot friction in the hub.

What should I do?

It is laced up to some nice Velocity rims.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to service that hub - or get it serviced by your LBS.  That much drag means that either it's full of dirt, or the grease has completely dried up or water contaminated, or the bearings have collapsed.

None of those are likely to be fatal, but you would be well advised to open that hub up and clean it out, check the bearings, and re-grease it.  Or have your shop do it for you.

Comment: Yes, and it's certainly worth trying to save it.

Comment: I took it to the shop but I wish I would have opened it up and taken a look.  Let me see what they say before I give a check mark.

Comment: Talked to the shop and they said it was in need of service and may need a new bearings.  Since I don't have the tool to knock out the bearing just as good I took it in.

Comment: Turns out it needs a new drive shell and they are on back order.

Answer (score 2):

The webpage for [Chris King Hubs](https://chrisking.com/hubs) says they are easy to service.

They supply lots of [info sheets](https://chrisking.com/tech/tech_PDF), like this [hub exploded view](https://chrisking.com/files/pdfs/CLASSIC-rear.pdf), and [manual](https://chrisking.com/files/upload/instructions/ClassicManual.pdf).

So I would take it apart and service it. They also sell parts, and since it's a high-end hub I would put some effort into saving it.

Comment: I took it to the shop but I wish I would have opened it up and taken a look.